# ...zum Verhältnis und im Verhältnis zum Verhältnis

Tags: translation

Ich schlug im Wiktionary 'Verhältnis' nach und fand dieses Beispiel.

> Im Verhältnis zwischen zweien ist das Verhältnis das Dritte als negative Einheit, und die zwei verhalten sich zum Verhältnis und im Verhältnis zum Verhältnis; so ist unter der Bestimmung Seele das Verhältnis zwischen Seele und Leib ein Verhältnis

Ich versuchte, es zu übersetzen, aber mein Deutsch-fu reicht nicht. Was bedeutet es?

Comment: Seems to be about *Verhältnis* in the sense of affair/relationship. Other than that, it doesn't make much sense to me (maybe troll entry/erroneus edit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist antiquiertes, literarisches Deutsch aus einem theologischen Text, den Søren Kierkegaard im Jahr 1849, also vor 165 Jahren, in dänischer Sprache geschrieben hat. Der Text trägt den Titel »Sygdommen til Døden« (Deutsch: »Die Krankheit zum Tode«) und ist auch in englischer Sprache unter dem Titel »The Sickness Unto Death« erschienen.

Im ersten Abschnitt dieses Textes definiert Kierkegaard »das Selbst« (»the self«) als ein Verhältnis (»relation«) zwischen dem Selbst und eben diesem Verhältnis. Er gibt also eine rekursive Definition, in der die Begriffe »Selbst« und »Verhältnis« durch die Beziehung (also einem Verhältnis) dieser Begriffe zueinander definiert sind. In der englischen Übersetzung ist daher auch von »relation's relating itself to itself in the relation« die Rede, was ich aber für ebenso unverständlich wie die deutsche Version halte.

Zu beachten ist unter anderem auch, dass man in modernem Deutsch die Substantive »zweien« und »zwei« groß schreiben müsste.

---

Ich versuche mal eine stückweise Erläuterung bzw. Interpretation des zitierten Textes:

**Im Verhältnis zwischen zweien ist das Verhältnis das Dritte als negative Einheit, ...**

Wenn zwei Personen in einer Beziehung zueinander stehen, nimmt die Beziehung selbst auch eine aktive Rolle in dieser Beziehung ein. Die Beziehung ist also der dritte Partner in der Beziehung zwischen zwei Menschen, und meist wirkt diese Beziehung negativ auf die Beziehung ein.

**... und die zwei verhalten sich zum Verhältnis und im Verhältnis zum Verhältnis; ...**

Die beiden Personen haben nicht nur eine Beziehung zueinander, sondern sie haben auch eine Beziehung zu dieser Beziehung.

**...so ist unter der Bestimmung Seele das Verhältnis zwischen Seele und Leib ein Verhältnis**

Unter dieser Prämisse ist auch die Seele eines Menschen als eine Beziehung anzusehen, nämlich als die Beziehung zwischen dem Körper und der Seele.

Answer (score 2):

This is from a philosopher (Kierkegaard, actually). In his works *Verhältnis zu* usually means position or attitude towards something. He talks about the Self in a philosophical sense here.

That said, it's heady stuff, not originally written in German (and in 1849 at that) and you'd have to be read in and acquainted with his works to make any sense of it. This is true for reasonably well-educated native speakers as well, so don't feel too disappointed.

Comment: Da stellt jemand in einem Forum, das die deutsche Sprache zum Inhalt hat, eine Frage in deutscher Sprache, und dann wird in einer anderen Sprache geantwortet? Warum?

Comment: Weil es als Folgekommentar zu Grantwalzers Kommentar geplant war (der in Englisch ist), dann aber doch als eigene Antwort gepostet wurde. Und weil der Fragesteller, ausweislich seines Profils Kanadier, Englisch zumindest verstehen dürfte. Wo ist das Problem?

Comment: Das Problem ist, dass hier auch Leute mitlesen, die zwar Deutsch, aber nicht Englisch sprechen. Es gibt ja auch z. B. Italiener oder Russen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen, ohne Englisch zu beherrschen.

Comment: Das gilt aber auch umgekehrt: Gerade Deutschlernende haben bisweilen Fragen, ohne bereits gut genug Deutsch zu sprechen um die Antwort zu verstehen. Wie gesagt, SE ist an sich eine englischsprachige Seite, "German Language" nur eine von vielen Unterseiten. Überall wird Englisch gesprochen, oder zumindest verstanden.

Comment: Jemand, dessen Deutschkenntnisse nicht ausreichen um eine deutschsprachige Antwort zu verstehen, schriebe seine Frage wohl kaum auf Deutsch. Da der Fragesteller die Frage in korrektem Deutsch gestellt hat, und sich seine Frage auf einen Satz bezog, der so extrem unverständlichen ist, dass ihn auch die meisten Muttersprachler nicht verstehen würden, ist anzunehmen, dass er eine Antwort in gewöhnlichen Umgangsdeutsch sehr wohl verstehen würde.

Comment: Die Diskussion ist müßig, weil schon aus der Frage hervorgeht, dass hier jemand an der deutschen Sprache und ihren Spitzfindigkeiten interessiert ist. Es geht darum, das Verständnis bei dieser konkreten Frage zu fördern und Wissen zu verbreiten. Also keine Angst Hubert, du musst nicht Englisch sprechen, wenn du nicht willst, und die deutsche Sprache verkümmert auch nicht, weil sie jemand auf Englisch erklärt. Aber es muss auch niemand Deutsch sprechen. Immerhin sind die Stack-Foren international und daher auch eine große Wissensplattform.

Comment: Danke, damit ist auch aus meiner Sicht alles gesagt. Wenn jemand das ausführlicher diskutieren möchte (ich werde auch in Zukunft situativ in Deutsch und/oder Englisch posten) würde ich dazu Meta vorschlagen: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/772/what-language-is-preferrable-for-answers-to-questions-written-in-german